# Subfigures: fail to inset 6 pictures in two rows

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm using the Frontier template to insert figures, but I keep coming up with errors. I do upload caption and subcaption packages. only one of the figures can show up and no matter how I adjust the size of them, I still fail to inset them.

The errors include:

> Not in outer par mode. Illegal measure of unit (this appears at first \begin(subfigure)

> Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal measure of unit ( this appears at all other \begin(subfigure)

The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersHLTH} % for Health articles

\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}


\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, ragged2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figure2 11.jpg}
    \caption{11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figure2 12.jpg}
    \caption{12}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figure2 13.jpg}
    \caption{13}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figure2 21.jpg}
    \caption{21}
    \end{subfigure}    
    \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figure2 22.jpg}
    \caption{22}
    \end{subfigure}    
    \begin{subfigure}[hbt!]{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{figure2 23.jpg}
    \caption{23}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me fix this problem! Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The "Template for Frontiers Journal" that can be found on overleaf, explicitly states "If you are submitting a figure with subfigures please combine these into one image file with part labels integrated."

Comment: Thanks for your notice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code contains various inaccuracies which, taken together, result in the unwanted layout. Take a look at the following modifications. Observe the uses of `%` after selected instances of `\end{subfigure}`, the uses of `\hfill`, and the purging of all `\centering` instructions as they do nothing useful.

Incidentally, when I try to recompile the code shown below on Overleaf, with the `frontiersHLTH` document class instead of `article`, I get an error message, about the file `frontiersHLTH.cls` not being found. That's why I use `article` for the example at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}     % I don't have access to 'frontiersHLTH'
%% (I've simplified the preamble to the bare minimum)
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.25\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure2 11}
    \caption{11}
    \end{subfigure}% <-- note the '%' comment char.
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure2 12}
    \caption{12}
    \end{subfigure}% <-- note the '%' comment char.
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure2 13}
    \caption{13}
    \end{subfigure} % leave a blank line to assure a par. break

    \medskip % insert a bit of vertical whitespace
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure2 21}
    \caption{21}
    \end{subfigure}% <-- note the '%' comment char.
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure2 22}
    \caption{22}
    \end{subfigure}% <-- note the '%' comment char.
    \hfill  
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure2 23}
    \caption{23}
    \end{subfigure}
    
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is super helpful!

Comment: Hi very kind Mico. Are you able to adjiust the code of David Carlisle that I have put in the question- bounty? Always always....thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Hi! My family and I are about to board a 5-hour flight from Honolulu to San Diego. (We’re having a great vacation…) Let me get back to you after I make it to San Diego.

Comment: My first and last vacation was when I was 12 years old. Who knows how beautiful the place will be and I had my first dose of vaccine on the 6th and recovered late this afternoon. This vaccine is a bomb :-(

Comment: This is one of the answers that I really want to vote down because it's the class that changes everything. Everything looks nice and smooth in `article` class, but `frontiersSCNS` or `frontiersHLTH` is not as straightforward. Your answer does not work in the original `frontiersHLTH` class.

Comment: @kensaii - I clearly stated at the top of my answer that the `frontiersHLTH` document class was *not* available on Overleaf at the time of the writing of this answer, and that I was therefore using a fallback document class (the `article` class). I believe the OP was fully aware of this caveat when they accepted my answer. But, sure, go ahead and downvote my posting if that makes you feel better.